# How can I use regular expression or any other method to sub a specific pattern of a string (python 2.7)?

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

So the string url I have is `'http://helloworld.net/b/c/3?nw=174057&csid=fire.clan.com/gram/&din=&rand=52710&w=400&h=112'`. This is in python 2.7.

Now the parameter rand in the url keeps changing and is always a 5 number length so it can be `rand=12345` or `99999` and etc

Now I want to change that in this case (`'rand=52710'`) to something like `'sub'` or just `''`

I have made attempts at this by using `https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions` but didn't come up with a solid solution

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: @FHTMitchell why am I given a downvote?

Comment: Oh right maybe but I made several attempts at it...
I read up on here `https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions` and came up with a solution of `match = re.search(r'rand=\d\d\d\d\d', url).group()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Regex**.

**Ex:**

```
import re
u = 'http://helloworld.net/b/c/3?nw=174057&csid=fire.clan.com/gram/&din=&rand=52710&w=400&h=112'
print re.sub("rand\=\d+", "SUB", u)
```

**Output:**

```
http://helloworld.net/b/c/3?nw=174057&csid=fire.clan.com/gram/&din=&SUB&w=400&h=112
```

Comment: should we just give the answer with no attempts (+1 anyway)?

Comment: Sorry, I am just practicing in stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Without regex, assuming that your claim "*now the parameter rand in the url keeps changing and is always a 5 number length so it can be rand=12345 or 99999*" holds true:

```
url = "http://helloworld.net/b/c/3?csid=fire.clan.com/gram/&din=&rand=52710&w=400&h=112"
index = url.rfind("rand=")
if index != -1:
    url = url[:index] + url[index+11:]  # add 'sub' between url parts if you want it
# http://helloworld.net/b/c/3?csid=fire.clan.com/gram/&din=&w=400&h=112
```